# Why my 2 components in bootstrap overlay each other when I shrink the web page?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I tried to play around with this contact form: https://www.prepbootstrap.com/bootstrap-template/contact-form-map
and I used it on my webpage. It looks like this:

```js
$("#trigger-overlay2").click(function() {
  // $(this).toggleClass("active");
  $(".overlay-boxify2").toggleClass("open");
});
```

```css
.overlay-boxify,
.overlay-boxify2 {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s, visibility 0s 0.5s;
  transition: opacity 0.5s, visibility 0s 0.5s;
}
.overlay-boxify.open,
.overlay-boxify2.open {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s;
  transition: opacity 0.5s;
  z-index: 9999;
}
.overlay2 {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url(../img/grid.png);
  background: rgba(222, 222, 222, 0.95)
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
  .overlay2 {
    overflow-y: scroll;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<a id="trigger-overlay2" href="#contact">Trigger!</a>
<div class="overlay2 overlay-boxify2">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="tos-logo-contact">
        <a href="./index.html">
          <img src="../img/logo.png" alt="logo">
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">

        <form id='contacts_form' action="#download" class="contact-list form-horizontal">
          <div class="field-row col-xs-12">
            <input class="form_item form-control" type="text" id="name2" name="name2" placeholder="Name" />
          </div>
          <div class="field-row col-xs-12">
            <input class="form_item form-control" type="email" id="email" name="email2" placeholder="Email" />
          </div>
          <div class="field-row col-xs-12">
            <textarea class="form_item form-control" style="resize:none" cols="30" rows="14" id="message" name="message2" placeholder="Message" title="some placeholder."></textarea>
          </div>
          <div class="field-row col-xs-12">
            <div class="col-xs-6 button-send">
              <input id="sendmessage" type="submit" class="form_submit sendbutton" value="Send" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6 button-cancel">
              <button id="cancelContact" type="button" name="cancelContact" value="cancel" class="sendbutton">Cancel</button>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div id="contact_results"></div>
        </form>

      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div>
          <div class="panel panel-default ">

            <div class="text-center ourOffice">
              <h4>Our Headquater:</h4>
              <div>
                Street
                <br />City, Country
                <br />
                <a href="mailto:mail@mail.com" target="_top">mail</a>
                <br />
              </div>
              <div id="map1" class="map">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fyw6kajm/5/ (just hit `trigger` link).

When the webpage is wide enough, it works:

[image]

But when I make it smaller, my input form is gone:

[image]

How can I fix it and show my form before the map?

Comment: I've moved your code into a Stack Snippet @randomuser1. A JS Fiddle link on its own is not sufficient as if the link were to die this question would lose context and be of little use. The question itself should always include all the relevant code required to reproduce the issue for this reason.

Comment: Thank you @HiddenHobbes, I will keep it in mind in the future :)

Comment: No problem @randomuser1, glad I could help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that the `field-row` `div`s containing your `inputs` are `float`ed to the `left`. This takes them out of the document flow and will require them to be cleared otherwise the containing `form` will collapse in `height` (it effectively thinks there is nothing inside it). To fix, add the `clearfix` class to the `form`.

```js
$("#trigger-overlay2").click(function() {
  // $(this).toggleClass("active");
  $(".overlay-boxify2").toggleClass("open");
});
```

```css
.overlay-boxify,
.overlay-boxify2 {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s, visibility 0s 0.5s;
  transition: opacity 0.5s, visibility 0s 0.5s;
}
.overlay-boxify.open,
.overlay-boxify2.open {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s;
  transition: opacity 0.5s;
  z-index: 9999;
}
.overlay2 {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url(../img/grid.png);
  background: rgba(222, 222, 222, 0.95)
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
  .overlay2 {
    overflow-y: scroll;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<a id="trigger-overlay2" href="#contact">Trigger!</a>
<div class="overlay2 overlay-boxify2">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="tos-logo-contact">
        <a href="./index.html">
          <img src="../img/logo.png" alt="logo">
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">

        <form id='contacts_form' action="#download" class="clearfix contact-list form-horizontal">
          <div class="field-row col-xs-12">
            <input class="form_item form-control" type="text" id="name2" name="name2" placeholder="Name" />
          </div>
          <div class="field-row col-xs-12">
            <input class="form_item form-control" type="email" id="email" name="email2" placeholder="Email" />
          </div>
          <div class="field-row col-xs-12">
            <textarea class="form_item form-control" style="resize:none" cols="30" rows="14" id="message" name="message2" placeholder="Message" title="some placeholder."></textarea>
          </div>
          <div class="field-row col-xs-12">
            <div class="col-xs-6 button-send">
              <input id="sendmessage" type="submit" class="form_submit sendbutton" value="Send" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6 button-cancel">
              <button id="cancelContact" type="button" name="cancelContact" value="cancel" class="sendbutton">Cancel</button>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div id="contact_results"></div>
        </form>

      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div>
          <div class="panel panel-default ">

            <div class="text-center ourOffice">
              <h4>Our Headquater:</h4>
              <div>
                Street
                <br />City, Country
                <br />
                <a href="mailto:mail@mail.com" target="_top">mail</a>
                <br />
              </div>
              <div id="map1" class="map">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```